# Unable to load CordaService

Tags: corda

I have a CordaService that looks like this:

```
@CordaService
class MyService(private val services: AppServiceHub) : SingletonSerializeAsToken() {
  private companion object {
    private val log = loggerFor<MyService>()
    init {
      BraidCordaJacksonInit.init()
    }
  }

  init {
    println("***** MyService Initializing ****") 
  }
}
```

The service has been behaving fine for quite some time. For an unknown reason, it’s no longer being initialised by the runtime.

The node's logs show that the cordapp has been successfully identified and loaded:

```
I 12:13:58+0100 [main] Main.printBasicNodeInfo - Loaded CorDapps                         : my-cordapp-0.1, corda-core-3.1-corda {}
```

If I run the node using NodeDriver:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  driver(DriverParameters(
      isDebug = true,
      waitForAllNodesToFinish = true,
      startNodesInProcess = true) {
    listOf(
        startNode(providedName = CordaX500Name("PartyA", "London", "GB"))
    ).map { it.getOrThrow() }
  }
}
```

... the corda service is correctly initialised:

```
***** MyService Initializing ****
[INFO ] 12:17:09,934 [driver-pool-thread-0] (AbstractNode.kt:487) internal.Node.installCordaService - Installed io.bluebank.MyService Corda service {}
```

Is there something specific I need to add to encourage the scanner to locate the class?

Thanks,
Fuzz

Answer (score 0):

This was our fault. Someone had removed the cordapp from `./build.gradle` `deployNodes` configuration!